# Why is a interface data member public and static?

Tags: java, oop

Why does java make a interface data member public & static implicitly?

Comment: By "data member" you mean "field", right?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You can just paste the link why you have posted the explanation in the comment ?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Because the only official answer is *"the JLS says so"*. The JLS doesn't provide reasons for their design, only the design itself.

Comment: @NambiNarayanan: links are context. I make sure that the things I post have a self contained value, as everyone should.

Comment: `Interface` variables are `static` because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists.

Comment: This is confusing.  If an `interface` is declared inside another class, it is implicitly static, but it doesn't have to be public.  Methods declared in the interface are implicitly public and abstract, but not static.  I don't know what an "`interface` variable" is, but if you declare a variable whose type is an interface type, it can be public or not, or static or not.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't see how your reference to 9.2 is relevant.  This is only talking about methods that an interface implicitly inherits from the `Object` class, i.e. `toString()`, `equals()`, etc.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, I think the question is about constants.

Comment: @ajb: ah, I totally read past the 'in Object' part. It isn't applicable here indeed; removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces only describe external behavior, or "how others see objects of the class implementing this interface" - from this point of view it's rather useless to define something so inherently coupled to internal behaviour as a field. If one wants to prescribe internal behaviour, abstract classes are clearly the way to go.

Comment: No answer abt  public & static

Comment: Yes, I wait for the day someone wants to define private methods on interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Smutje's answer a bit: interfaces aren't allowed to define their own data.  Because of that, I suspect, the language designers felt that the only legitimate use of data definitions was to define a constant that might be usable by clients; thus, the `Action` interface in `javax.swing` has a method

```
void putValue(String key, Object value)
```

and the interface also defines some constants that can be used for the `key`:

```
public static final String ACTION_COMMAND_KEY = "ActionCommandKey";
public static final String ACCELERATOR_KEY = "AcceleratorKey";
```

etc.  Of course, since those are constants, they aren't data that would be stored in each object that implements the interface.  But those are the only kinds of data fields allowed in interfaces.